# Finding data for dates that fall in certain range

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem trying to figure out the occupancy rate for a series of vacation rentals that fall in the timeframe of January 2021 to the end of March 2021 in MySQL. I've realized that I'm running into the issue of excluding rentals that began before the timeframe but continued during it or ended after the timeframe (ex. checked in in December 2021 but checked out mid-January 2021, checked in December 2021 and checked out April 2021, etc.). As someone recently getting back into SQL, I'm having trouble figuring out the way to include those as well. I believe that this is the best way to do it - to use the DATEDIFF function on those that checked in earlier or checked out later to give me a negative number that I can then subtract from the length of their stay in order to give me the number of nights spent in this time period. I'm not able to figure out where my syntax is incorrect though, as I keep getting ERROR 1064 by line 14. If you have any other suggestions on the best way to achieve this, please share them as I'm trying to learn the best way to get things done in MySQL.

This is my current code:

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SELECT 
bookings.`listing_id`,
bookings.`checkin_date`,
CASE
  WHEN DATEDIFF(bookings.`checkin_date`,'2021-04-01') < 0
    THEN DATEDIFF(bookings.`checkin_date`,'2021-04-01')
      ELSE 0
END AS `OccBeginning`,
bookings.`checkout_date`,
CASE
  WHEN DATEDIFF('2021-07-31',bookings.`checkout_date`) < 0
    THEN DATEDIFF('2021-07-31',bookings.`checkout_date`)
      ELSE 0
  FROM bookings
    WHERE bookings.`type` = 'guest' AND bookings.`cancelled` = '0'
     GROUP BY bookings.`listing_id`;
```

Comment: *This is my current code* This is not complete code but a fragment. So it's not possible to define what is "line 14" in which the error occures. PS, Use LEAST()/GREATEST() instead of your CASEs.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete code then line 14 is the `ELSE 0`, just before `FROM bookings`. The syntax error is that you haven't ended the case statement.

ie instead of

```
CASE
  WHEN DATEDIFF('2021-07-31',bookings.`checkout_date`) < 0
    THEN DATEDIFF('2021-07-31',bookings.`checkout_date`)
      ELSE 0
  FROM bookings
```

you should have

```
CASE
  WHEN DATEDIFF('2021-07-31',bookings.`checkout_date`) < 0
    THEN DATEDIFF('2021-07-31',bookings.`checkout_date`)
      ELSE 0
END -- <-------------- needs the END here
  FROM bookings
```